# Implementing Paging in existing scaffolded project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, paging, scaffolding, ef-database-first

I have a Database first project that I have scaffolded to create the CRUD.

Is it possible to add paging?  My issue is that my Index() is an async task and not a view result.

I have followed this article [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and a few others..but they all assume that your index is an ActionResult.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

        return View(await db.TABLENAME.ToListAsync());
    }
```

The above  is my current Index().

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString) { 

return View(students.ToList());
}
```

The above is the assumed ViewResult.

How would you handle updating paging with async?

A limited preview would be great. I am new to c#.

Comment: Best tool for paging so far i have seen is datatable.js its a javascript library for paging.

Comment: This application has 1000+ users inputting 50,000 to 100,000 rows a day of data. The output would be so large that it would cause browser crashes. A javascript library unfortunately...thank you for the suggestion though! That would work for smaller applications.